# iOS 14.2, UIKit programatically title is not showing up

Tags: swift, uikit

I am making an app programatically. I have a TabBarController with three tabs. Each tab represents a viewController. In this view controllers if I am setting title, but title is not showing up. Screen Shot : [image: Screen Shot]

TabbarController codes:

```
class TabbarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let vc1 = ViewController()
        let vc2 = SearchViewController()
        let vc3 = LibraryViewController()
        
        vc1.title = "Home"
        vc2.title = "Search"
        vc3.title = "Library"
        
        vc1.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
        vc2.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
        vc3.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
        
        let nav1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc1)
        let nav2 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc2)
        let nav3 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc3)
        
        nav1.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        nav2.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        nav3.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        
        
        setViewControllers([vc1,vc2,vc3], animated: true)
    }

}
```

ViewController Codes:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        self.title = "Home" // This title is not showing up

    }
}
```

Comment: try this ```self.navigationItem.title = "Home"```

Comment: Not working, tried that.

Comment: Make sure your controller has a navigation bar and font color is opposite of the background color.

Comment: How can I make sure my controller has a navigation bar, please?

Comment: Try to set the title from the storyboard and check. is it working?

Comment: I have deleted the storyboard.

Comment: Can you attach ss?

Comment: Pleas check I have attached a screenshot.

Comment: Change this line ```setViewControllers([nav1,nav2,nav3], animated: true)```

Comment: Now visible...?

Comment: Yes, You just saved me, its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is inside the `TabbarController` class file.
You have set the view controller instead of the wrapped UINavigationController.

So, use this line

```
setViewControllers([nav1,nav2,nav3], animated: true)
```

instead of `setViewControllers([vc1,vc2,vc3], animated: true)`